# Removing duplicated values from two-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to remove duplicated values from a two-dimensional array.

I have used `array_unique` function to the two-dimensional array. And it seems that this function does not work for two-dimensional array.

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Here is my array output below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
      [Is_Hide] => 0
            [Key] => LHo0VTLsFcI7wWq2EWQy1nUp5U13pXWLXt8s0775
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Is_Hide] => 0
            [Key] => GiSKlOZXRhXTmHKLAeEMPUWoJMs08ftWeenCMrPk
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Is_Hide] => 0
            [Key] => LHo0VTLsFcI7wWq2EWQy1nUp5U13pXWLXt8s0775
        )
)
```

Comment: Well... I don't see the duplicate values ?

Comment: may be duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

Comment: No duplicates - nothing to remove. Case closed!

Comment: Sorry.. I have updated my question. Edit: Change value data..

Comment: solved this problem like this => if(in_array($value['Key'],array_column($list,'Key'))){ continue; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP's [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function:

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```

See [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#97285).